# Why Kotlin sortBy() seems to operate in reverse order?

Tags: java, sorting, kotlin

When I perform:

```
val array = arrayListOf<String?>(null, "hello", null)
array.sortBy { it == null }
println(array)
```

I expect it would print `null` values first as that's the selector I specified. However, `println(array)` returns `[hello, null, null]`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression:

```
it == null
```

returns a `Boolean` result `true` or `false` and this is what you use to sort the array.
 The value `true` is greater than `false`, you can see it by executing:

```
println(false < true)
```

which will print

```
true
```

With your code:

```
array.sortBy { it == null }
```

for every item that the expression `it == null` returns `false` it will be placed before any item for which it will return `true`. 
So do the opposite:

```
array.sortBy { it != null }
```

Result:

```
[null, null, hello]
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `sortBy` performs the *transformation* you specify on each of the objects, and then it sorts by the natural order of the transformed objects.

You transformed your objects into trues (if the object is null) and falses (if the object is not null). Here is your transformed array list:

```
true false true
```

And this will be sorted according to natural order of booleans, which is falses go first, so the second element will swap with the first, producing the result.

To achieve your desired result, use `{ it != null }`.

Comment: Even `{ it != null }` will leave the non-null values together but in an unspecified order.  (In this case there's only one, which is why it's not obvious.)  I'd suggest `{ it ?: "" }` instead, which will sort every item, putting nulls (and any empty strings) first.

Comment: @gidds from every test I made the order of the non nulls is the same as in the presorted list.